# ASP.NET MVC publishing umbraco 7 project to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I made a local ASP.NET MVC project using umbraco 7 CMS (http://localhost:23..).

I upload the project by publishing it in Visual Studio 2013 and filling in the correct server information. After completion the files are stored on my webserver (checked using filezilla) in the right map. When I go to the URL I get the error:

```
Forbidden (403)
You do not have permission to access this document.
```

I already searched for solutions but they clearly say that when using a SQL CE database (I'm using SqlServerCe.4.0) that after the publishing is complete the website should be visitable:

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/60106-Publish-umbracoCms-718-content-on-server

EDIT: Tried it with a simple MVC 5 project and it resulted in the same problem (with one.com as hosting)

Comment: Can you try upload a simple Mvc website and see if it work.
Make sure your hosting service provide Windows and IIS such as this
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/14623-Error-403-Forbidden

Comment: Good idea, will try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Simple MVC project gives the same error.

Comment: Then I think you should check your hosting plan again, or contact your service provider.
I think it is your environment problem

Comment: I tried it on a second hosting (from one.com) and it shows the same error, so I guess the problem is not the hosting.

Comment: One.com I am not sure if they support .net? Unless I am mistaken

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong. I have not use one.com before, but from the feature list I only see php and MySql - didn't see anything on iis and .net.
Are you sure they support asp .net site?

Comment: I automatically assumed that such a big hosting company would support .NET, I guess they don't. Will try another hoster with .NETsupport.

Comment: Yes, always check what technologies these company support. Contact your hosts as @Alan Tsai mentioned.